# Why did the sea travelers in Yonah 1 proselytize instead of becoming righteous gentiles?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, commentaries, rashi, navi-prophets, yonah-jonah-book-of

We read in Yonah 1 about the men who traveled on a boat with Yonah. When the sea ceased storming we read:

"And the men feared the Lord exceedingly, and they made sacrifices to the Lord and made vows." (Yonah 1:16)

Rashi explains that they promised to convert (Rashi on Yonah 1:16)

Question: Why did they convert instead of becoming righteous gentiles? If Torah does not require everyone to convert why did they?

Comment: It sounds spontaneous to me, not something informed by a misunderstanding of torah (which, as gentiles, they presumably didn't know either way).

Comment: Keep in mind that prior to casting lots they prayed to their own gods to save them. No response. Jonah tells them that if they throw him overboard, "his" G-d will make the storm stop. That's what happened. I think that proof alone convinced them that if nothing else, when they pray, they should pray to the "Jewish" G-d. (Yes, it is one and the same, we know. But, perhaps, the event convinced them that being Jewish meant praying to the "Jewish" G-d.)

Comment: People tend to be rather greatful when their lives are saved.

Comment: Is your question specific to these individuals? Can’t you ask why anyone would choose to convert?

Comment: @JoelK Anyone is not written about in the Torah. These men are

Comment: Pretty sure that there are opinions that they became גרי תושב. Doesn’t answer your question since those opinions that they became גרי צדק still exist.